# How to read type of element for Oracle collection type?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

I have Oracle collection type defined as:

```
type tab_foo as table of obj_foo
```

Where `obj_foo` is defined as:

```
type obj_foo as object
```

By calling:

```
select * from sys.all_types where typecode = 'COLLECTION';
```

I can get metadata for all the collection types, however there is no information what is the type of element contained in the collection.

How to retrieve collection element type metadata from oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `ALL_COLL_TYPES`, which lists all collection types.  The column you are interested in is `ELEM_TYPE_NAME`.